# Partial Page Caching and VaryByParam in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to use the new partial page caching available in ASP.NET MVC 3.  In my view, I'm using:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("RenderContent", Model); %>
```

Which calls the controller method:

```
[Authorize]
[OutputCache(Duration = 6000, VaryByParam = "*", VaryByCustom = "browser")]
public ActionResult RenderContent(Content content)
{
   return PartialView(content);
}
```

Note that both the original view and the partial view are using the same view model.

The problem is that `VaryByParam` doesn't work - `RenderContent()` always returns the same cached HTML no matter what view model is passed to it.  Is there something about `VaryByParam` that I don't understand?

Comment: How is the calling action method decorated, cache-wise? Also, VaryByParam has nothing to do with the Model passed to the action method - it has to do with the parameters (query string, form, etc) sent by the browser - *to the calling action method*, in this case.

Comment: No caching is specified on the calling action method.

Comment: @bzlm, partial page caching *does* have to do with input parameters, and not with querystring/form fields. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx, section Output Caching Improvements.

Comment: @Jappie You're right. Good stuff! Technically though, "automatically varies the output cached entries when you have explicit parameters on your action method" is true even for ASP.NET MVC 1 for normal actions using GET. (Still have to `VaryByParam` there though.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  It looks like the issue is that VaryByParam, when the input parameter is an object, uses `ToString()` on that object to determine it's uniqueness.  So this leaves two options:

1. Overriding `ToString()` to provide a unique identifier.
2. Passing a unique identifier as an additional parameter:

   ```
   <% Html.RenderAction("RenderContent", Model, Model.Id); %>

   [Authorize]
   [OutputCache(Duration = 6000, VaryByParam = "id", VaryByCustom = "browser")]
   public ActionResult RenderContent(Content content, string id)
   {
      return PartialView(content);
   }
   ```

Comment: Great answer, just what we needed. We used option 1. Using `return GetHashCode().ToString();` in the `public override string ToString()` to create a unique code for each object. This seem to work fine.

Comment: Don't use ```GetHashCode().ToString()``` as a unique ID. Hash codes are _not_ designed to be unique, only unique-ish.